# Exception when creating a cell in Uitablesource getcell method in xamarin ios

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I am using google places api to provide suggested search. So it searches for the api for every character hit. I have a table source which gets updated.
Here is the GetCell method

```
public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView,NSIndexPathindexPath)
{
  var cell = base.GetCell(tableView, indexPath) as CityCell;
  cell.SubscriteToCheckEvent(() =>
{
    var ddd = cell as CityCell;
    viewModel.ZipCode = cell.CityNameText.Text;
    viewModel.SearchStoresCommand.Execute(true);
 });
   return cell;

 }
```

I am getting an exception when i am trying to update the value to fast

```
Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
```

Is there any way that I can avoid this exception?

Any suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: What is the base class? Typically, you don't call `base.GetCell` unless your base is another class created by you. If you are not inheriting from your own class, then you should call `tableView.DequeueReusableCell` to get the cell.

Answer (score 0):

The way you invoke the "GetCell" method is incorrect.

This is a sample for GetCell:

```
public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            MyTableCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (CellID) as MyTableCell;
            if (null == cell) {
                //Init custom cell
                cell = new MyTableCell (UITableViewCellStyle.Default, CellID);
                //Bind delete event
                cell.CellClicked += delegate {
                    //Do something for click event
                };
            }
            return cell;
        }
```

And this is the complete sample about UITableView data management I wrote for other, you should take a look:

[UITableViewDataManagementSample](https://github.com/lwnwowone/UITableViewDataManagementSample)

You need share more code, or we can't help you.